# Oracle hex to number conversion dword

Tags: oracle

I am trying to convert hex to number. if I use

```
SELECT To_Number('F8EF7F2C', 'xxxxxxxx')  FROM dual;
```

The result is 4176445228. This is qword result.

What I want to get is dword result which -118522068

How can i achieve that?

Thanks,

Update:

```
SELECT to_number('F8EF7F2C', 'xxxxxxxxxx')-Power(2,32) FROM dual
```

seemed to work for this value 'F8EF7F2C'. But changing the hex value to

```
SELECT to_number('0208A5FA', 'xxxxxxxxxx')-Power(2,32) FROM dual
```

produces wrong result -4260846086. The correct result is 34121210 which is produced by

```
SELECT to_number('0208A5FA', 'xxxxxxxxxx') FROM dual
```

I can verify the correct results from PC calculator in programmer mode in Dword.

Comment: Subtract it from `2^32`?

Comment: hi, Zerkms, I updated my question. it works by half.

Comment: 1. Substract that expression from `2^32`. 2. Do that only if it overflows `2^31 - 1` (`0x7FFFFFFF`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I know the terms, your qword is an unsigned 32-bit integer, while dword is a signed 32-bit integer.

Here's a little test with some hex values:

```
with hex as (
   select '00000000' hex from dual union all
   select '0208A5FA' hex from dual union all
   select '7FFFFFFF' hex from dual union all
   select '80000000' hex from dual union all
   select 'F8EF7F2C' hex from dual union all
   select 'FFFFFFFF' hex from dual
)
select hex.hex
     , to_number(hex.hex,'XXXXXXXX') unsigned
     , case
          when to_number(hex.hex,'XXXXXXXX') >= power(2,31)
          then to_number(hex.hex,'XXXXXXXX') - power(2,32)
          else to_number(hex.hex,'XXXXXXXX')
       end signed
     , mod(
          to_number(hex.hex,'XXXXXXXX') + power(2,31)
        , power(2,32)
       ) - power(2,31) signed_alternative
  from hex
 order by hex.hex
/
```

The output of the query is:

```
HEX        UNSIGNED        SIGNED SIGNED_ALTERNATIVE
-------- ---------- ------------- ------------------
00000000          0             0                  0
0208A5FA   34121210      34121210           34121210
7FFFFFFF 2147483647    2147483647         2147483647
80000000 2147483648   -2147483648        -2147483648
F8EF7F2C 4176445228    -118522068         -118522068
FFFFFFFF 4294967295            -1                 -1
```

Column `SIGNED` is calculated like suggested in the comment by @zerkms, a `CASE` expression is used to only subtract `2^32` when it overflows.

Column `SIGNED_ALTERNATIVE` gives same result, but does it by first adding `2^31`, then taking the modulo `2^32`, and then subtracting `2^31` again.

The `CASE` expression might be a teeny bit more efficient as it has less numeric operations to perform on these `NUMBER` values (had it been floating point operations, the modulo version might have been faster as it could have been optimized to bit operations ;-)

Comment: Thank you Kim. That's exactly what I need. Thanks to Zerkms too.